# como puedo ponder un area especifica de spawn

Tags: unity3d

hola estoy haciendo un spawn de zombis enemigos para mi juego, pero aparecen fuera del mapa, como puedo hacer que aparezcan dentro de un área especifica que sea dentro del mapa?, lo mismo pasa con otros objetos como por ejemplo cajas de municion y cosas asi.

```
public class Zombie_Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToSpawn;
    public GameObject parent;
    public int numberToSpawn;
    public int limit = 20;
    public float rate;
    float spawnTimer;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    spawnTimer = rate;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (parent.transform.childCount < limit)
    {
        spawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (spawnTimer <= 0f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberToSpawn; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x + GetModifier(), this.transform.position.y + GetModifier())
                    , Quaternion.identity, parent.transform);
            }
            spawnTimer = rate;
        }
    }

}
float GetModifier()
{
    float modifier = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    if (Random.Range(0, 2) > 0)
        return -modifier;
    else
        return modifier;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que faltan ciertos datos clave para poder solucionar tu problema.
Uno de ellos: ¿Dónde está el objeto que contiene este script?
A priori, el algoritmo instancia cada x tiempo un nuevo objeto alrededor del objeto en el que se encuentra, por lo que es clave que tengas centrado este objeto en la región donde quieres instanciar los zombies.

Por otro lado, cuando pones "if (Random.Range(0, 2) > 0)" en la función GetModifier(), solo hay un valor válido que no cumple la condición (0) mientras que hay "infinitos" valores que sí la cumplen (valores decimales entre 0 no incluido y 2 incluido). No sé exactamente si esa es tu intención. ¿Tal vez querías poner mayor que 1 en lugar de mayor que 0?

Comment: Si crees que faltan datos, mejor abstenerse a responder y pedir la información necesaria en un comentario.

Comment: No tengo todavía puntos suficientes en el foro en castellano y nadie le estaba dando respuesta. De todos modos, si un moderador ve esto, puede mover la respuesta a comentario (cosa que me ocurrió en el foro en inglés).